# How to add missing dates when calculating count on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, date-arithmetic

I have a sales table that records sale of an item. simplified version is below

| ID | ItemID | SaleTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 2020-12-01 12:44:22 |
| 2 | 1234 | 2020-12-01 17:12:22 |
| 3 | 1234 | 2020-12-02 12:44:22 |
| 4 | 1234 | 2020-12-04 17:12:22 |

i am writing a query to count items sold each day which is working fine and giving following results.

| ID | ItemID | Date | Sale count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 2020-12-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 1234 | 2020-12-02 | 1 |
| 3 | 1234 | 2020-12-04 | 1 |

how do I include days where no sale was made with zero count like following.

| ID | ItemID | Date | Sale count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 2020-12-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 1234 | 2020-12-02 | 1 |
| 3 | 1234 | 2020-12-03 | 0 |
| 4 | 1234 | 2020-12-04 | 1 |

Comment: Do you want to query the sales per day for each item _distinctly_? First I recommend avoiding the column `ìd` at all as technical keys often are more confusing than informational in the result. Let `item_id` be your first column and sort your query by that first, then by `date`. Be extra careful on days where no samples of a certain item got sold as there can be `null` values which can let you miss some rows of your result!

Comment: Maybe a `left join` in combination with the `coalesce()`-function could do a simple job for you, but i'm currently looking up for that myself

Comment: Do you want the same range for every item?  A fixed range?  A range based on only the first and last date for each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a recursive query to generate the dates. you can then `cross join` that with the list of distinct items available in the table, and bring the table with a `left join`. The last step is aggregation:

```
with cte as (
    select min(convert(date, saletime)) as dt, max(convert(date, saletime)) as max_dt from mytable
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt), max_dt from cte where dt < max_dt
)
select c.dt, i.itemid, count(t.id) as sale_count
from cte c
cross join (select distinct itemid from mytable) i
left join mytable t 
    on  t.itemid = i.itemid
    and t.date >= c.dt
    and t.date <  dateadd(day, 1, c.dt)
group by c.dt, i.itemid
```

In a real life situation, you would probably have a separate referential table to store the items, that you would use instead of the `select distinct` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME = '2020-11-28 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME = '2020-12-13 00:00:00.000';

;WITH AllDays AS (SELECT @start_date AS [DATE]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
                   FROM   AllDays
                   WHERE  [Date] < @end_date),
     Items AS (SELECT distinct itemid from Sales)
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.itemid, a.[DATE]) AS [ID], i.itemid as [ITEMID], a.[DATE],  count(s.itemid) AS [SALE COUNT]
     FROM Items i
     CROSS JOIN AllDays a
     LEFT JOIN Sales s ON a.[DATE] = convert(date, s.salestime) and i.itemid = s.itemid
     GROUP BY i.itemid, a.[DATE]
     ORDER BY i.itemid, a.[DATE]
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Results (for two item Ids and 16 days):**

```
+----+--------+-------------------------+------------+
| ID | ITEMID | DATE                    | SALE COUNT |
+----+--------+-------------------------+------------+
| 1  | 1234   | 2020-11-28 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 2  | 1234   | 2020-11-29 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 3  | 1234   | 2020-11-30 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 4  | 1234   | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2          |
| 5  | 1234   | 2020-12-02 00:00:00.000 | 1          |
| 6  | 1234   | 2020-12-03 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 7  | 1234   | 2020-12-04 00:00:00.000 | 1          |
| 8  | 1234   | 2020-12-05 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 9  | 1234   | 2020-12-06 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 10 | 1234   | 2020-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 11 | 1234   | 2020-12-08 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 12 | 1234   | 2020-12-09 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 13 | 1234   | 2020-12-10 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 14 | 1234   | 2020-12-11 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 15 | 1234   | 2020-12-12 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 16 | 1234   | 2020-12-13 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 17 | 1235   | 2020-11-28 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 18 | 1235   | 2020-11-29 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 19 | 1235   | 2020-11-30 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 20 | 1235   | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 21 | 1235   | 2020-12-02 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 22 | 1235   | 2020-12-03 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 23 | 1235   | 2020-12-04 00:00:00.000 | 1          |
| 24 | 1235   | 2020-12-05 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 25 | 1235   | 2020-12-06 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 26 | 1235   | 2020-12-07 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 27 | 1235   | 2020-12-08 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 28 | 1235   | 2020-12-09 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 29 | 1235   | 2020-12-10 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 30 | 1235   | 2020-12-11 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 31 | 1235   | 2020-12-12 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
| 32 | 1235   | 2020-12-13 00:00:00.000 | 0          |
+----+--------+-------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses a calendar table which keeps track of all the dates you want to appear in your report:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CAST('20201201' AS date) AS dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
    FROM dates
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= '20201231'
)

SELECT
    t.ITEMID,
    d.dt,
    COUNT(t.ID) AS [SALE COUNT]
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON CAST(t.SALETIME AS date) = d.dt
GROUP BY
    t.ITEMID,
    d.dt
ORDER BY
    d.dt;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give `null` values on days without sales?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  `COUNT`ing a `NULL` yields a count of zero.

Comment: `count(*)` does appearently but does `count(field_name)` too?

Comment: Please research the documentation for the `COUNT` function, in whatever database you are using.

Comment: Huh it seems you're right. So I learned something here too

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have noted, one solution is a recursive CTE.  You specifically want to do that for one itemid, so I would suggest:

```
with dates as (
      select min(convert(date, saletime)) as dte, max(convert(date, saletime)) as max_dte
      from mytable
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dt), max_dt
      from dates
      where dte < max_dte
    )
select c.dt, v.itemid, count(t.id) as sale_count
from dates d cross join
     (values (1234)) v(itemid) left join
     mytable t
     on t.itemid = v.itemid and
        t.date >= d.dte
        t.date <  dateadd(day, 1, c.dt)
group by d.dte, v.itemid;
```

Note that if you have more than 100 days, then you need to also add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to avoid an error in the date generation.

If you want the solution for *all* item ids, then GMB's answer is better answer.